# How to add -fPIC in Android.bp file?

Tags: android, relocation

I recently suffer from the relocation issue in android 10: **relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 out of range: 8589967360 is not in [-4294967296, 4294967295]**. And I tried to add **cflags:["-fPIC"]** in the android.bp, but it does not work. Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

The code shows below:

I defined a class in timeStampTrans.cpp:

```
    class timestampTrans
    {
    public:
        timestampTrans();

        static void init(double defScale);

    };
```

And when I use this class in timeStampTransWrapper.c:

```
    static timeStampTrans tt[10];
```

This error was reported.

Comment: Please add the code that you have tried with the expected output and the output of your code...this will help us answering your question

Answer (score 1):

Root cause found. It is because that there are so many uninitialized global variables in my code, which fulfill the .bss section.